# Error not raising from BULK INSERT IN try block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

hi i have written the below code inside a try block but does not raising error to catch block . but stand alone bulk insert generating error messages.

```
BEGIN TRY

SET @sql = 
                '
                    BULK INSERT dbo.vw_Data_Import_ISO_CSP_OPMHC_Premium--<-- table view
                    FROM ''' + @SourceFilePath + '''
                    WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' );
                '

EXECUTE (@sql)

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

        SELECT 
            @error_number = ERROR_NUMBER(), 
            @error_message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
            @error_line = ERROR_LINE()
        SELECT @error_description = 'T-SQL error number ' + CAST(@error_number AS VARCHAR(10))  + ' on line ' + CAST(@error_line AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.'

END CATCH
```

Comment: Can u include catch block please

Comment: Add the problem TRY/CATCH code to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman added the try and catch block .

Comment: What is the value of `@SourceFilePath`?

Comment: Also, post the error message that the standalone code generates.

Comment: @WEI_DBA passing a csv file at sourcefile path, it produces error getting truncation error while doing stand alone bulk insert

Comment: @DanGuzman thank u for the help but actually my csv file will cause a truncation error in the standalone bulk insert execution but in the procedure some records getting inserted and not generating any error messages. ie while debugging it is not jumping to the catch block after the bulk insert

Comment: @Sambhu, try adding 'MAXERRORS = 0' to your `BULK INSERT` statement. The default is 10.

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you. its working fine with MAXERRORS

Comment: @Sambhu, thanks for confirming. I added `MAXERRORS = 0` to the code in my answer too.

Comment: @DanGuzman your tip about MAXERRORS was the answer for me... It's a bit buried in the comments. Is there a way to make it more obvious?

Comment: @WalterdeJong, I edited my answer to make it more visible.

Comment: FYI the intended code really doesn't serve any purpose. Whether or not you include try catch code, and error will be raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not raising an error in the `CATCH` block, only assigning a variable value. Try adding `RAISERROR`:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET @sql = ' BULK INSERT dbo.vw_Data_Import_ISO_CSP_OPMHC_Premium --<-- table view 
FROM ''' + @SourceFilePath + ''' WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', MAXERRORS = 0 );'
    EXECUTE (@sql);
END TRY BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        @error_number = ERROR_NUMBER(), 
        @error_message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
        @error_line = ERROR_LINE();
    SELECT @error_description = 'T-SQL error number ' + CAST(@error_number AS VARCHAR(10))  + ' on line ' + CAST(@error_line AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.';
    RAISERROR(@error_description, 16, 1);
END CATCH;
```

In SQL Server 2012 and later, the CATCH block can be simplified using `THROW`:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments, a non-zero `MAXERRORS` specification is useful in situations where some records in the source cannot be parsed and may be skipped. The default is 10 if not specified.